# Use launchSettings.json for multiple startup projects

Tags: visual-studio

Visual Studio has the possibility to debug multiple executable projects. For example when you want to debug a client/server application where you have both, the client and the server as separate executable in your solution, you select both projects as startup projects so that both executables are compiled and started when you run the application(s).

So far so good, but this is a setting that is stored for the solution and is local for every user (it is stored in the .vs folder which gets deleted when your clear the folder). Also it cannot be checked in into source control. That means that I have to tell this to everyone in our group to be able to debug the apps.

I was hoping I can do something similar with the launchConfig.json, but I couldn't find out how to do it. Has someone already done this?

Comment: The only reason the .vs folder isn't checked into source control is because of the .gitignore file.  If you edit the .gitignore to have Git not ignore the relevant folders or files, then the settings can be checked in.  That being said, I am not sure what you mean by "when you clear the folder"?  The .vs folder should stick around unless you are manually deleting it.

Comment: @PierrePlourde. We are having many issues with the .vs folder regarding keeping things up to date. It seems that some internal caches do not work at times, and its necessary to delete the .vs folder to bring VS up again. I was assuming the .vs folder shouldn't be touched at all since it is also hidden. Additionally the problem is that other things, other than the startup projects are stored which means I could get the environment from my colleague. Nevertheless the question is if it can be solved with the launchSettings.json too, or if it doesn't support it.

Comment: understood.  I don't believe it does, since it applies only to the particular app, and so would perforce be different for the 2 apps.  Have you checked to see if the settings are stored in the .sln file?

Comment: Yes I did. There's nothing stored in the sln file.